# JavaScript Dynamic margins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, margin

I have a jQuery file that dynamically resizes my HTML header. For some reason, it doesn't resize at all. Why doesn't it?

```
    /* PAGE SIZE */
    var WIDTH = $(window).width();
    var width = WIDTH - 1053;
    var WIDTH = width.toString();
    $('li.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-has-children.menu-item-323').css('margin-left', WIDTH);
```

Comment: We'll need to see the HTML...

Comment: your WIDTH without 'px' at the end

Comment: how do you know it's not working? there is a chance that the `WIDTH - 1053` is negative, hence you might think it's not working, it appears to be easily recognized as working when the `margin-left` is positive. You don't need to add the suffix `px` when passing the value in `css` method, it's optional.

Answer (score 0):

**See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f4yLx3kz/1/**

You need to add 'px' to your CSS width setting.

```
var winWidth = $(window).width(),
    itemWidth = winWidth - 1053;

$('li.menu-item-323').css('margin-left', itemWidth + 'px');
```

A few more suggestions:

- WordPress outputs a lot of classes on menu items but the menu item number `.menu-item-323` should be sufficient to target just that menu item
- For your own readability you should set some more understandable variable names in JS instead of just mixing upper and lower case
- No need to convert the width to a string